# How to align image as shown below

Tags: subfloats, overleaf

I was trying to align images as shown in the picture below. I am new to latex need help

[image]

```
\usepackage{graphicx} % takes care of graphic including machinery
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\section{Experiments}
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
%\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height = 3cm]{real_data/st.png}}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height = 3cm]{real_data/dta.png}}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height = 3cm]{real_data/e.png}}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height = 3cm]{real_data/ot.png}}\\
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height = 3cm]{real_data/ge_30.png}}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height = 3cm]{real_data/ge_30.png}}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height = 3cm]{real_data/e_30.png}}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height = 3cm]{real_data/30.png}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:overleaf]?

Comment: I was trying to do this in overleaf @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: The problem is independent of which editor you are using.

Comment: Thanks i have edited to subfigures

Comment: What did you try so far in order to achieve the expected output?

Comment: @leandriis I have included the code i have tried till now

Comment: I was able to align two rows and 4 columns images but i was unable to keep those two images at the top as shown in the figure

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please always provide complete MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}`. Now page layout of your document is unknown.
- Your code fragment contain only 8 pictures, but in question you show 10 pictures (consequently in MWE below I repeat last two of them.
- Since all images has equal size, it is very sensible to use of key `Gin` and on this was make figure code significantly shorter.
- `subfigure` is obsolete package, instead it I use `subcaption` and environment `\subfloat` (which is also supported by `subcaption` newest than version 3.1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove "demo"
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex,belowskip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
   \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=3cm, height = 3cm}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/st.png}}
\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/dta.png}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/e.png}}
\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/ot.png}}
\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/ge_30.png}}
\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/ge_30.png}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/e_30.png}}
\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/30.png}}
\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/e_30.png}}
\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{real_data/30.png}}

\caption{My figures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the code in your question, I guess, you currently use the [`subfigure`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package. Please keep in mind that this particular package is considererd deprecated and should be replaced by either the [`subfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or the [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package.

Here, I included two examples using both packages. These examples will result in slightly different alignments, especially with respect to the horizontal space between adjacent images and between the images and the margin. Caption position, spacing, image size and otehr parameters can of course be adjusted to suit your needs.

| Output of example 1 | Output of example 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

(Vertical red lines indicate margins.)

---

**Example 1:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig} % or \usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\adjustboxset*{width=0.22\columnwidth, valign=c}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}\quad
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}\medskip
 
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}\quad 
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}\quad 
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}\quad 
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}\medskip
 
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}\quad
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}\quad 
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}\quad 
\subfloat[]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}} 
\caption{picture}
\label{fig:key}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

**Example 2:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \hspace{0.225\textwidth}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \hspace{0.225\textwidth}
        
        \medskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        
        \medskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.225\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}    
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{figure caption text goes here} 
        \label{fig:key}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```